# $http.post what format for data (body) when binary?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http

I want to send a binary file (image for example) in an angularjs $http.post.

I have the data in a nodejs Buffer object, which is an implementation Uint8Array.

I tried:

```
$http.post("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload",
                data,
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + dSvc.GO.onlineStorage.D1.accessResponse.access_token,
                        'Dropbox-API-Arg': JSON.stringify({
                            "path": path,
                            "mode": "overwrite",
                            "mute": true
                        })
                    }
                }
            )
```

But when the data gets to the server, is is bigger, and the image is corrupt.

If my starting point is a Buffer (Uint8Array) how do I get from there to a field that can be sent in the body of an $http.post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOH, I just had to add , transformRequest: [] so that angularjs would not crap on the data.

```
$http.post("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload",
            data,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + dSvc.GO.onlineStorage.D1.accessResponse.access_token,
                    'Dropbox-API-Arg': JSON.stringify({
                        "path": path,
                        "mode": "overwrite",
                        "mute": true
                    })
                }, transformRequest: []
            }
        )
```